# NoMethodError in CartsController#destroy - Agile Web Development with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, null, nomethoderror

I'm learning Rails following the book Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and I got stuck with this Error:

```
NoMethodError in CartsController#destroy
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the action Destroy of the Cart controller. The error info references to the line `@cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]`:

```
# DELETE /carts/1
# DELETE /carts/1.json
def destroy
  @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to store_url,
     notice: 'Your cart is currently empty'}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

This action is called from the "Empty car" button in the `views/carts/shown.html.erb`

```
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Everything was working fine, but after creating a migration that added the column `price` to the table `LineItems` and modifying the method `add_product` from `Carts` for handling this new column, the destroy action is not working anymore.

this is `models/cart.rb`

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id, product_price)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, price: product_price)
    end
    current_item
  end

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end

end
```

This is `models/line_item.rb`:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    price * quantity
  end
end
```

And this is the action `create` from `line_items_controller` that is used for adding products to the Cart:

```
before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

...

# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json
def create
  session[:counter] = 0
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, product.price)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Before this action, the method `set_cart` from the module `CurrentCart` is called:

```
def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
```

When I run the controllers tests there are no failures. This is the test for the action `destroy` from Cart:

```
test "should destroy cart" do
  assert_difference('Cart.count', -1) do
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    delete :destroy, id: @cart
  end

  assert_redirected_to store_path
end
```

I can't see what is the cause of this error and I would like your help.

**edit**

This is the output from the server:

```
Started DELETE "/carts/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-16 12:23:43 -0500
Processing by CartsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"hLsBQ0fR5b9M2lfxMc5McU1+dqtnZ2OKABRZV79vdHo=", "id"=>"15"}
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "15"]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  LineItem Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 15]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["id", 91]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:58:in `destroy'
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you loading ``@cart`` for your destroy action, maybe with a ``before_filter``? It looks like its empty.

Comment: It seems like `before_action :set_card, only: [:create]`, should at least be `before_action :set_card, only: [:create, :destroy]`.

Comment: @dgilperez @ptd this `before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]` is used in `line_items_controller` where the cart is only needed to create a new `LineItem`. In `carts_controller` I'm using this filter: `before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy`. In think in `carts_controller` the method `set_cart` is the one of the own controller, but in `line_items_controller` the `set_car` method is the one from the `CurrentCart` module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tried from rails console and got this:

```
2.2.0 :001 > carro = Cart.find(25)
  Cart Load (12.9ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
 => #<Cart id: 25, created_at: "2015-02-17 01:10:49", updated_at: "2015-02-17 01:10:49"> 
2.2.0 :002 > carro.destroy
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
/home/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:75: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
/home/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:79: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
/home/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:83: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
/home/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:102: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
  LineItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 25]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["id", 116]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["id", 117]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["id", 118]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:80:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
```

What happens is that `/home/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:75: warning: circular argument reference - reflection` is caused for a bug in `activerecord` according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/issues/380).

What I did was update the rails version. I was using `rails 4.0.0`, after updating to `rails 4.1.2` the problem was solved.