# rails 4 many to many though join model, undefined method 'name' for:NilClass, sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Hey guys I have a pretty simple many to many set up between User Movies through WatchList. It's an app that searches the itunes api for movies, here I'm adding the abilty for user to save searched movies to a personal list. I'm using Rails 4.1.1 and sqlite3.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  has_many :watch_lists
  has_many :movies, through: :watch_lists

  def add_movie(movie)
  self.movies << movie
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :watch_lists
  has_many :users, through: :watch_lists
end

class WatchList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

I problem is when I try and add the movie which uses the itunes id for the DB :id. in the saves_controller on line 7 it throws undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass. I can't figure it out, nothing is nil? Movie saves to db fine, with proper info. It's when I try and create the join table. What is rails trying to call 'name' on???

**line 7 raises error current_user.movies << @movie => undefined method 'name for nil:NilClass**

```
class SavesController < ApplicationController
def create
  temp_movie = aquire_movie
  @movie = Movie.new(temp_movie.local_db_movie_info_hash)

  if @movie.save
    current_user.movies << @movie #### => LINE 7 ERROR undefined methond 'name for nil:NilClass
    redirect_to @movie
  end
end

private

def aquire_movie
  movie_data = itunes_results[:results][0]
  TemporaryMovie.new(movie_data)
end

def itunes_results
  data_retriever.get_data(params[:movie_id], search_by_id: true)
end
```

end

Here is the schema as well.

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150330012300) do

  create_table "movies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "auth_token"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["auth_token"], name: "index_users_on_auth_token"
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email"

  create_table "watch_lists", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "movie_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

**Update**

I just had a friend clone this repo and he had no issues so it's some sort of gem /database issue ??

Comment: Seems like an issue with your user and definitely sounds like a data issue. Try doing this from a fresh start and see what happens. Drop the whole database and log in from an incognito browser. That seems like the case given that it's complaining about an error on what I can only perceive as your user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I kinda found an answer through this. [NoMethodError in CartsController#destroy - Agile Web Development with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545975/nomethoderror-in-cartscontrollerdestroy-agile-web-development-with-rails-4)

Basically updated rails 4.1.1 => 4.1.2, and error went away. some sort of bug in Active record I believe is what it came down to.

I was also "getting warning: circular argument reference - reflection" when I ran the rspec. Which lead me to the post above.

Comment: Well done! Now, you can help other readers selecting this answer.

Comment: Error was also present in Rails 4.0.0.  I upgraded a project, and the association worked, with no other change to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to [raise](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) an exception in every create.

The standard pattern for create is:

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
  if @movie.save
    redirect_to @movie
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

When the movie belongs to a current_user:

```
def create
  @movie = current_user.movies.new(movie_params)
  if @movie.save
    redirect_to @movie
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: I think your line 7 is right, raise is not expected to be here.

Comment: yea but its line 7 that's throwing the undefined method 'name' error for nil:NilClass. I just had a friend clone this repo and he had no issues so it's some sort of gem /data base issue ??